# Update kubernetes secrets doesn't update running container env vars

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Currenly when updating a kubernetes secrets file, in order to apply the changes, I need to run `kubectl apply -f my-secrets.yaml`. If there was a running container, it would still be using the old secrets. In order to apply the new secrets on the running container, I currently run the command `kubectl replace -f my-pod.yaml` .
I was wondering if this is the best way to update a running container secret, or am I missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For k8s' versions >v1.15: `kubectl rollout restart deployment $deploymentname`: this will
    restart pods incrementally without causing downtime.

Answer (score 23):

[The secret docs for users](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod) say this:

> Mounted Secrets are updated automatically
>   When a secret being already consumed in a volume is updated, projected keys are eventually updated as well. The update time depends on the kubelet syncing period.

Mounted secrets are updated. The question is when. In case a the content of a secret is updated does not mean that your application automatically consumes it. It is the job of your application to watch file changes in this scenario to act accordingly. Having this in mind you currently need to do a little bit more work. One way I have in mind right now would be to run a [scheduled job in Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/scheduled-jobs/) which talks to the Kubernetes API to initiate a new rollout of your [deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#updating-a-deployment). That way you could theoretically achieve what you want to renew your secrets. It is somehow not elegant, but this is the only way I have in mind at the moment. I still need to check more on the Kubernetes concepts myself. So please bear with me.

Comment: Another way to monitor the secret would be to use `inotify` and watch the directory where it is mounted.

Comment: The Secrets docs also note that a 'container using a Secret as a subPath volume mount will not receive Secret updates' - this is what had me stumped for a little while.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming we have running pod mypod [mounted secret as mysecret in pod spec]

We can delete the existing secret

```
kubectl delete secret mysecret
```

recreate the same secret with updated file

```
kubectl create secret mysecret <updated file/s>
```

then do

```
kubectl apply -f ./mypod.yaml
```

check the secrets inside mypod, it will be updated.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone (like me) want to force rolling update pods which are using those secrets. From this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13488#issuecomment-356892053), the trick is to update an Env variable inside the container, then k8s will automatically rolling update entire pods

```
kubectl patch deployment mydeployment -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"mycontainer","env":[{"name":"RESTART_","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}'
```

Comment: Do you know how to update/extend an existing deployment yaml with a new secret? We do have multiple secrets in existing deployment yaml files and want to extend the deployment with new secrets. We use secrets from volumes.

Answer (score 0):

By design, Kubernetes won't push Secret updates to running Pods. If you want to update the Secret value for a Pod, you have to destroy and recreate the Pod. You can read more about it [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-and-pod-lifetime-interaction).

Comment: On http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/, at “Mounted Secrets are updated automatically” it says otherwise – at least I understand it this way.  Or is this another case?

Comment: This answer is true for [mounts with subPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#mounted-secrets-are-updated-automatically) where secrets are not updated automatically.

Comment: [stakater/Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) is able to watch configmap or secret, then rolling upgrades the relevant deployment