# Kubernetes make changes to annotation to force update deployment

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Hey I have a wider problem as when I update secrets in kubernetes they are not implemented in pods unless they are ugprades/reschedules or just re-deployed; I saw the other stackoverflow post about it but noone of the solutions fit me [Update kubernetes secrets doesn't update running container env vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945800/update-kubernetes-secrets-doesnt-update-running-container-env-vars)

Also so the in-app solution of python script on pod to update its secret automatically https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/updating-secrets-from-a-kubernetes-pod-f3c7df51770d but it seems like a long shot and I came up with solution to adding annotation to deployment manifest - and hoping it would re-schedule pods everytime a helm chart would put a new timestamp in it - it does put it but it doesn't reschedule - any thought how to force that behaviour ?

```sh
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xxx
  namespace: xxx
  labels: xxx
  annotations:
    lastUpdate: {{ now }}
```

also I dont feel like adding this patch command to ci/cd deployment, as its arbitraty and - well doesnt feel like right solution

```sh
kubectl patch deployment mydeployment -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"mycontainer","env":[{"name":"RESTART_","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}'
```

didn't anyone else find better solution to re-deploy pods on changed secrets ?

Comment: Kubernetes' `Deployment` controller reacts to changes to the `annotations` on the pod template - `.spec.template.metadata.annotations`.

Comment: Does Helm also own/generate the Secret, or is it being managed externally?

Comment: Came here to say what @BogdanL said.

Put the annotation under:

spec.template.metadata.annotations

and it should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kubernetes by itself does not do rolling update of a deployment automatically when a secret is changed. So there needs to a controller which will do that for you automatically. Take a look at [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) which is a controller that watches if some change happens in ConfigMap and/or Secret; then perform a rolling upgrade on relevant DeploymentConfig, Deployment, Daemonset and Statefulset.

Add `reloader.stakater.com/auto` annotation to the deployment with name `xxx` and have a ConfigMap called `xxx-configmap` or Secret called `xxx-secret`.

This will discover deployments/daemonsets/statefulset automatically where xxx-configmap or xxx-secret is being used either via environment variable or from volume mount. And it will perform rolling upgrade on related pods when `xxx-configmap` or `xxx-secret` are updated

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xxx
  namespace: xxx
  labels: xxx
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
```